# MyBatis: underscore not mapped to camelcase

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

My problem is simple. I have a column name product_name in my product table in my mysql database but in my Product class (java), camelcase is used in productName. MyBatis is not mapping product_name to productName. Any solution for this? I had no problem in Hibernate before but right now I need to use mybatis for development

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but for those that may come across this, MyBatis [supports](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Auto-mapping) mapping underscores to camel case

config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Then your sql can look like:

```
select product_name, product_description, ...
from products
```

or even just

```
select *
from products
```

Answer (score 10):

Underscore to camel case mapping can be enabled in spring-based configuration through a customizable SqlSessionFactory, like that:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactory factory = sessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    factory.getConfiguration().setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);
    // other configurations
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<resultMap>` tag in MyBatis to return the result. For example:

```
<resultMap id="result" type="userModel">
        <result property="id" column="USER_ID"/>
</resultMap>
```

In the above code, in `type="userModel"` userModel is defined in a config file where there is a mapping of userModel with a model java class which will have the corresponding setter/getter method for id.
For more info on this, refer the following Doc:

[MyBatis Doc](https://mybatis.googlecode.com/files/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simple solution for this, but I do not consider it proper solution.
I added `as` to match with a property of my class.

`select product_name as productName from products;`